# react native undo of xcode changes for native functions not reflecting in git

Tags: ios, xcode, git, react-native

When i use a native function of react native such as camera and edit some files in xcode according that library(example camera) and suppose it doesn't work. Then i undo it with discarding the changes in git but the changes for ios are still there, i can see those changes in xcode, for android all the changes are discarded but for xcode it doesn't work. Here is my .gitignore file :

```
# OSX
#
.DS_Store

# Xcode
#
.vscode
build/
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
*.xccheckout
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
*.hmap
*.ipa
*.xcuserstate
project.xcworkspace

# Android/IntelliJ
#
build/
.idea
.gradle
local.properties
*.iml

# node.js
#
node_modules/
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log

# BUCK
buck-out/
\.buckd/
*.keystore

# fastlane
#
# It is recommended to not store the screenshots in the git repo. Instead, use fastlane to re-generate the
# screenshots whenever they are needed.
# For more information about the recommended setup visit:
# https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/source-control/

*/fastlane/report.xml
*/fastlane/Preview.html
*/fastlane/screenshots

# Bundle artifact
*.jsbundle
```

Which files i should remove in .gitignore to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If I am comprehending correctly, you have edited the React Native's native Xcode files. If so, try removing the "node_modules/" from your gitignore.

P.S. it is not a good practice to edit 3rd party files(node modules in this case) if you have them in .gitignore, this makes it difficult to debug and fix bugs later on. You can always fork a repository if you wish to make any changes in those.

Comment: no i have not edited files inside node_modules, i dragged and dropped a file from node_modules/react-native/LinkingIOS/RCTLinking.a(not sure abut exact path but i was doing it for deep links) into xcode, so i have made a change but when i discarded all changes through git then i can still see that file RCTLinking file in the xcode.